# Pi Zero 2W uart configuration?

Tags: serial, pi-zero-w-2

I found this answer [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 (PiZeroW, Pi4 or later models)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3-pizerow-pi4-or-later-models/107780#107780)

It was very helpful to understand the uart situation on the Pi 4. But when I tried the same config file on a Pi-Zero 2W it did not work. Fair enough it's a different board. However I can't find similar information for the 2W. The reference in the answer only covered up to the Zero and the 4. Where can I dig up how to enable the other uarts on a Pi-Zero 2W.  Specifically I'm trying to re-use the hat eeprom pins.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 (PiZeroW, Pi4 or later models)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3-pizerow-pi4-or-later-models)

Comment: @Dougie no sorry, it does not work for Pi zero 2W.  It helped me with Pi4 yesterday.

Comment: You should use modprobe for RPi 3.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the [RP3A0 SOC](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/processors.html#rp3a0) on the *Pi Zero 2 W* doesn't have any additional UART.
It has the same peripheral module as ALL early Pi and only has 2 UART

Only the [BCM2711](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/processors.html#bcm2711) used in the Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, the Raspberry Pi 400, and the Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 has additional UART.